# Import Union type with a qualified name

Tags: elm

So I have two union types: `JobStatus` and `TaskStatus`.

```
module Data.Job exposing (..)


type JobStatus
    = Submitted
    | Started
    | Finished
```

-

```
module Data.Task exposing (..)


type TaskStatus
    = Created
    | Running
    | Finished
```

and I import them into a third module

```
module Home exposing (..)


import Data.Job as Job exposing (JobStatus(..))
import Data.Task as Task exposing (TaskStatus(..))


type alias Model =
    { jobStatus : JobStatus
    , taskStatus : TaskStatus
    }


model : Model
model =
    { jobStatus = Finished
    , taskStatus = Finished
    }
```

But `Finished` is too confusing, I want to write it as `JobStatus.Finished` or `TaskStatus.Finished` how can I do that?

Comment: I thought the compiler would complain that there are two values with the same name in the third module, and ask you to rename one. But to answer your question, you'd use `Job.Finished` or `Task.Finished`, rather than `JobStatus.Finished`.

Comment: @Sidney You are indeed correct and the compiler does complain. Also `Job.Finished` and `Task.Finished` is the right way to go.
I wonder what would happen if you had two union with some overlapping values in a single module.

Comment: Same error I believe, the compiler would ask you to rename one of them. You'd also get that error if you have two top-level functions with the same name, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you changed your import from this

```
import Data.Job as Job exposing (JobStatus(..))
import Data.Task as Task exposing (TaskStatus(..))
```

to this

```
import Data.Job as Job 
import Data.Task as Task
```

you can use Job.Finished and Task.Finished.